# How can I force an image and its caption to be on the same page?

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, captions

I am using the `caption` package, now I have one problem: In one case an image is placed at the bottom of one page, while its caption is placed on the top of the following page. In this case I would prefer the image to be also moved to the next page.

Actually my LaTeX code looks like this:

```
\begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics{sample.png}
    \captionof{figure}{the caption}
    \label{figure:sample}
\end{flushleft}
```

Is there some way to tell LaTeX that the graphic and the caption shall be seen as one unit and shall never be split up over 2 pages?

Comment: Why don't you use the `figure` environment?

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `minipage` environment enclosing figure and caption. Within `minipage` environments no pagebreak can occur.

Further there's the `samepage` environment for that purpose. Unlike `minipage`, `samepage` doesn't require a width argument.

Comment: Though further support of `\samepage` is doubtful, you could read about that in source2e.

Comment: thank you very much! minipage seems to work the best. is it maybe somehow possible to define in the preamble, that \includegraphics followed by \caption shall be automatically put in a minipage or do I have to add the minipage always manually?

Comment: It should be added in the document body. Shortcuts might be used. But you could define a new environment or command taking filename, caption and label as argument, that produces a minipage together with `\includegraphics`, `\caption` and `\label` if you desire to compress your code.

Comment: No, he should use the figure environment.

Comment: @MartinSchröder If he wants it to be able to float. If he knows the `caption` package and `\captionof{figure}{...}` it seems that he would like to avoid figures or floating, respectively, while keeping the caption below the image though. However, I agree with you recommending `figure` and preferring using and improving floating instead of avoiding it.

Comment: Shouldn't be `\nopagebreak` after the `\includegraphic`  enough?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to improve Stefan's answer by putting `minipage` inside `figure` environment. So image + caption can still be a floating object:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{sample.png}
    \caption{the caption}
    \label{figure:sample}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You don't need a minipage inside the figure environment. They all become a single entity.

Comment: I guess, there is a reason for him not using a floating environment.

Comment: Like if you are using multicols. Floats are not supported.