# Unequivocally force first reference to same page as the referred item?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, lyx, page-breaking

### Background

Writing a manual using LyX. All tables, figures, and source listings are always referenced in the paragraph (or enumerated step) that immediately precedes them. The preamble to the manual includes `\raggedbottom` to prevent large vertical spaces between list items.

### Problem

The problem can be seen here:

[image]

The heading "1.1 Hierarchies" (no orphaned headings allowed) and the reference to "Figure 1.1" should be at the top of Page 2, on the same page as the image.

### LaTeX Code

The images are added to floats so that they can have captions and cross-references. The LyX documents contain the following commands:

```
\float_placement H
```

I have tried changing the commands to:

```
\float_placement !htbp
```

These affect figure placement, but do nothing for the cross-references.

### LyX Code

This is the code that LyX generates:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{drawings/directory-hierarchy-01}

\caption{\label{fig:Example-Directory-Organization}Recommended Directory Organization}

\end{figure}
```

### Possible Solutions

1. `\begin{samepage} ... \end{samepage}`
2. `\clearpage`

The `\clearpage` option is possible when the manual is complete. The `samepage` environment needs tweaking.

### Question

What needs to be added to the document preamble to force the first cross-reference to remain on the same page as the item that is being referenced?

### Related

- [How can I force an image and its caption to be on the same page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/force-image-and-its-caption-to-be-on-the-same-page)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
- [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text/8633#8633)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Keeping tables/Figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Comment: 1) don't use floats if you don't want things to float. 2) if the layout is such that it's impossible for the reference and image to be on the same page don't expect TeX to perform magic. 3) if it's not covered in the answers to the above linked question, it's probably not going to be possible.

Comment: @Seamus: (1) How do you make captions and cross-references without a float, using LyX? (2) OpenOffice, Microsoft Word, and FrameMaker have a "keep with next" option that allows such behaviour (unfortunately, it requires manually setting every paragraph); I thought LaTeX would have similar. (3) This question is about keeping the tables/Figures on the same page, which is different than "close to".

Comment: (1) Using the `caption` package.

Comment: @Caramdir: At this point, there are over 220 listings, figures, tables, and captions... all within floats. The entire document is ih LyX. Converting all those items to use the `caption` package seems like a rather large effort, and seems counter to the "LyX-way": http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Figures

Comment: @Dave, also have a look at [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text/8633#8633) for a solution using the `float` package. If the answers there are still not good for you, please edit your question to indicate why. Otherwise this question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Dave From the wiki you linked to: "How do I get LyX to put the figure exactly where I want it?

Select Document→Settings.... In the Float Placement section, unset "Use Default Placement" and select "Top of Page", "Page of Floats", "Here, if possible" and "Ignore LaTeX rules". [...]

If you really insist, you can also simply select "Here definitely". This will insert the figure by all means at the current place. Note, though, that chances are high that this leads to ugly unbalanced pages. Usually, LaTeX does a rather good job in float placement if you do not restrict it too much."

Comment: @Seamus: (1) Initially, I let LaTeX place the floats, but it did a terrible job (for a technical manual). (2) I forced all images to be *Here definitely*. (3) I would prefer ugly, unbalanced pages (`\raggedbottom`) to enumerated lists with large inconsistent spaces between the items (which was the result when LaTeX placed the images where it deemed proper). (4) The results are shown in the question.

Comment: @Juan: I changed the question to show that I am using the `float` package, as described in the link you provided. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the relevant entry on the [UK's TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopagebrk), there is probably no way to automatically and conveniently do this.

Indeed, the two most simple solutions would be to use the `samepage` environment (which may not work in all situations) or manually insert `\clearpage` as needed.

My advise would be to leave the figures wherever they happen to fall, and only in the end add `\clearpage`'s as appropriate to break pages exactly at the places you want.

Sorry, there seems to be no “keep with next” in (La)TeX.

Comment: Not really a viable option. The manual is going to have multiple published revisions (adding new sections and chapters), so "in the end" will not happen. I tried `\samepage`, but it did not work as expected. Thank you for taking the time to look into this, though.